# Stuggling with WPF MVVM Unity, Generic Repository

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container

How can I inject my CustomerRepository into my CustomerVM view model? In my view, a WPF Page I have:

> ```
> <Page.DataContext>
>     <viewModel:CustomerVM/>
> </Page.DataContext>
> ```

But my view model constructor obviously has parameter passed in,

> ```
>     public CustomerVM(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
>     {
>         //this._customerRepository = customerRepository;
>     }
> ```

I get

> Type 'CustomerVM' is not usable as an object element because it is not
>   public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type
>   converter.

Really struggling to heck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the ling that gives you this error? or a snippet of the code ?

Comment: Please see [Here][1] 
I recommend the Viewmodel locator approach


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830199/setting-viewmodels-property-from-xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can initialize the DataContext within the XAML if you're using dependency injection.  Set the DataContext in the code-behind for the view so Unity can resolve the dependencies.  Try adding this to YourView.xaml.cs:

```
public YourView(CustomerVM viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

The above will work if you are resolving your views through Unity.  If not, you can also use the ServiceLocator to resolve the view model:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

public YourView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CustomerVM>();
}
```

You might also need to add the following somewhere in your registration code to setup the ServiceLocator if you're not using Prism:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(_unityContainer)));
```

Comment: As soon as I navigate to the view with the view model as parameter get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ????? Even though I have unitycontainer registering instance of CustomerVM??

Comment: See my edit above on using the ServiceLocator to resolve the CustomerVM.  If that doesn't work, can you post your Unity registration code?

Comment: Hi mike, dev machine is not here but in my app.xaml..cs i have overridden startup and codes something like: UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer container();        container.registertype<IRepository , CustomerRepository>();       container.registertype<CustomerVM>();          does this look right?   Cheers